# 'Component' is defined but never used - Angular

Tags: angular, eslint, typescript-eslint

We recently updated Angular to version 14 and all dependent packages to the most recent versions. After the update, we are receiving an eslint error stating that 'Component' is defined but never used unused-imports/no-unused-imports'  According to my knowledge, I believe Component we usually use in decorator and it is needed. Help me how to get rid of this warning.

[image]

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'money-control',
  templateUrl: './money-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./money-control.component.scss']
})
export class AMTabComponent { 
}
```

These are my configuration files for eslint
.myapp.eslintrc.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/master/src/schemas/json/eslintrc.json",
  "root": false,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": [
      "tsconfig.json",
      "tsconfig.*.json"
    ],
    "ecmaVersion": 2021,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "unused-imports"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
      "error",
      {
        "type": "element",
        "prefix": "myapp",
        "style": "kebab-case"
      }
    ],
    "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
      "error",
      {
        "type": "attribute",
        "prefix": "myapp",
        "style": "camelCase"
      }
    ],
    "@angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": [
      "off",
      {
        "accessibility": "explicit"
      }
    ],
    "arrow-parens": [
      "off",
      "always"
    ],
    "dot-notation": "error",
    "import/no-deprecated": "off",
    "import/order": "off",
    "no-restricted-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "paths": [
          "rxjs/Rx"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": [
      "error",
      {
        "default": [
          "static-field",
          "instance-field",
          "static-method",
          "instance-method"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": [
      "error"
    ],
    "no-unused-expressions": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": [
      "error"
    ],
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": [
      "error"
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/quotes": [
      "error",
      "single"
    ],
    "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off"
  }
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```js
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "**/node_modules"
  ],
  "root": true,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.js"],
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2021,
        "sourceType": "module"
      },
      "extends": ["./.myapp.eslintrc.json"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports": "off",
        "node/no-restricted-modules": [
          "error",
          {
            "paths": [
              {
                "name": "rxjs/Rx",
                "message": "Please import directly from 'rxjs' instead"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["tsconfig.json", "tsconfig.*.json"],
        "ecmaVersion": 2021,
        "sourceType": "module"
      },
      "extends": ["./.myapp.eslintrc.json"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/keyword-spacing": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
        "prefer-const": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off",
        "prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions": "off",
        "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
        "arrow-body-style": "off"
      },
      "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
          "typescript": {
            "project": ["tsconfig.json", "tsconfig.*.json"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "parser": "@angular-eslint/template-parser",
      "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/banana-in-box": "error",
        "@angular-eslint/template/no-negated-async": "off",
        "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": "error"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.component.ts"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"]
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.po.ts", "*.mock.ts","*.spec.ts"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/keyword-spacing": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
        "prefer-const": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/return-await": "off",
        "prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/return-await": "off",
        "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
        "arrow-body-style": "off"
      },
      "env": {
        "jasmine": true
      },
      "plugins": ["jasmine"],
      "extends": ["./.myapp.eslintrc.json"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide some more info about your .eslintrc.json? I don't see `unused-imports` flag included in the current spec. Where are you setting this rule?

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/

Comment: @khollenbeck I have added eslint configuration files and you can see now

Comment: Hello again. I apologize for the non reply. I was on vacation for a couple weeks. I'm not sure if this is still an issue for you. If so. Could you possibly set up a repo on github that reproduces the issue? Also what IDE are you using?

Comment: @khollenbeck I'm having the same issue after updating from angular 13 to 15. I have tried updating all the es-lint packages to the latest version and extending all the recommended rules... Nothing get's rid of the annoying error on all the decorators. I have been comparing the `.eslintrc` to that of a working angular 15 project and couldn't find anything causing the isue...

Answer (score 8):

## Rerun angular schematics

When using `ng add` instead of using your package manager (npm/yarn/...) angular runs scripts called `Angular Schematics`. These automate changes needed for packages to work as intended. So, whenever a package author recommends using `ng add` you really want to do so, because the package comes with these schematics that would otherwise not run.

By uninstalling eslint and adding it again using `ng add` you will fix the problem without having to disable or ignore any rules.

Just run (depending on your preferred package manager):

> yarn remove @angular-eslint/schematics

or:

> npm uninstall @angular-eslint/schematics

and then:

> ng add @angular-eslint/schematics

(and select 'y' for yes...)

*Run these 2 commands, and that should fix your problem. You might need to give your IDE a minute to re-check the files.*

Answer (score 1):

I had a look into the [implementation](https://github.com/sweepline/eslint-plugin-unused-imports/blob/master/lib/rules/no-unused-imports.js). So what this plugin does, is trying to use the `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` plugin. When any kind of error happens in the way, it falls back to ESLint's `no-unused-vars` rule. So likely the TypeScript ESLint plugin throws an error, and the ESLint rule is used, but it cannot understand the usage of the TypeScript decorator. To understand what kind of error the TypeScript ESLint plugin is throwing, I would recommend to directly use the `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` rule on your TypeScript files. After fixing the resulting errors, it should work again.

IMHO this plugin is obsolete and misleading. Instead you should configure the `no-unused-vars` rule for JavaScript files and the `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` for TypeScript files:

```
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.js",
      "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": "error"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": "*.ts",
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thx for looking into it, but the `@typescript-eslint` lib does not have an autofix rule. So running `ng lint --fix` will not actually fix the error, rather just point it out for you to fix it manually. So while close, it is not actually the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines should remove the eslint error:

```
    "no-unused-vars": "off"
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["off", { "ignoreRestSiblings": true }],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not solve the problem for me...

Answer (score -2):

You can disable the eslint rule that is being applied to the 'Component' import. To do this, you can add an 'eslint-disable' comment at the beginning of the import line, like this:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-imports */
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
/* eslint-enable no-unused-imports */
```

Comment: Why I need to disable, Component is needed and we are using in Decorator too right?